# Pause iframe on clicking div tag using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a site that has an iframe on it. So the first div tag from this site has some options that should be visible until the user hit the "next" div (AKA "blank page").

What I want to do is if the user clicks the "next" link, the previous div should be hidden because instead of showing it, it should be hidden for 10 seconds and then be shown. But the problem is that I'm only getting it done onclick. I assume it's because the iframe is running?

Is this possible?

Thank you for any input, and thank you for making the alert box because I'm using the same script over and over.

Here is the javascript:

```
var ifr = document.getElementById("ifr"); 
var s=document.getElementById("s"); 
var text = 'please <b>over </b> your message'; 

(document.getElementById("whileing").addEventListener("click",function(){ 
    var s=document.getElementById("whileing"); 
    var text = 'just start screen'; 
    ifr.removeChild(s); 
})
```

Comment: sorry for any bad grammer

Comment: Add some of your relational codes and add image/draft of the final output you want to achieve.